# Add <div> with a button click (HTML, CSS)

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering how I can add or remove a specific `<div>` by using buttons.

What I'm trying to do is create a `<div class="example">CONTENT</div>` that can be created by clicking a button. The div contains forms to be filled out, and the user should be able to add 14 forms(the page loads with the first form) to the page.

Each of these divs also needs to have a "Remove button" that will remove that specific div from the page.

Is this possible?

Comment: It is possbile. YOu can created elements using `document.createElement`, append them to existing elements by using `.appendChild(newELement)` and remove elements by calling `element.parent.removeChild(element)`

Comment: It is possible but with Javascript, not pure HTML and CSS.

Comment: Thanks @JohannesH. I found a a bit of tutorials for that, but how do I define the <div>content</div> that I want the button to add?

I'm found this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement

But I'm not sure how I can define everything that would get placed inside of the <div>, in that example it just creates text inside of the div.

Comment: `newDiv.innerHTML = "content"`

Comment: @JohannesH. OK, so do I add the .innerHTML to `var newDiv = document.createElement("div");` which would make it `var newDiv.innerHTML = document.createElement("div");`? And I place my <div>CONTENT</div> inside of the " " in ("div") ? Thanks

Comment: Also, I found [link]http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_createelement which is pretty but what i'm trying to do, except inserting <div> instead of another button

Comment: nope, do it one after another. `var newDiv = document.createElement('div'); newDiv.innerHTML = 'content';`

Comment: But I'd suggest you do some beginners tutorials on javascript before you start with your real project.

Comment: @JohannesH. You are right! I should, where is a good place to begin? Thanks for your help, btw!

Answer (score 0):

The function you're looking for is below (using jquery)

Javascript

```
$('.remove').click(function() {
    var removed = $(this).attr('id');
    $('div#'+removed).remove();
});
```

This function captures the click event on a button with class "remove" and grabs the buttons id. Then, with that id in memory, it traverses the DOM and removes the node that is of type: *div* and id: *our stored id*. Hope that makes sense!

HTML

```
<div id="1">Div 1<button class="remove" id="1">Remove</button></div>
<div id="2">Div 2<button class="remove" id="2">Remove</button></div>
<div id="3">Div 3<button class="remove" id="3">Remove</button></div>
<div id="4">Div 4<button class="remove" id="4">Remove</button></div>
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MVLP5/